# Cassandra: What does mean zero token in the cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I've noticed that the token for one of my nodes actually equals to `0`.

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
==========
Address    Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token                                       
                                                                          4611686018427387904                         
127.0.0.1  rack1       Up     Normal  162.5 KB        ?                   -9223372036854775808                        
127.0.0.2  rack1       Up     Normal  145.97 KB       ?                   -4611686018427387904                        
127.0.0.3  rack1       Up     Normal  162.26 KB       ?                   0                                           
127.0.0.4  rack1       Up     Normal  167.44 KB       ?                   4611686018427387904
```

Is it something wrong with my cluster?

Answer (score 2):

Tokens range from 0-2^64 (or 128 depending on partitioner). The value 0 is assigned to that node. This token is used for [consistent hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing). Nothing is wrong with 0.

Comment: For murmur3partitioner the valid token values are -2^63 to +2^63-1.

Comment: I use `Murmur3Partitioner` by default.